# Changing the CALayer anchor point

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

Changing the anchor point of a CALayer after a CATransform3dRotate gives weird results. I think the problem is, anchorPoint property is set on the previous state (no transform) of layer not the current state (after transform) of the layer.

[image]

Is there a way to change the anchorPoint of a CALayer's current state??

**Code for Transform:**

```
     CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

        transform.m34 = -(1.0/800.0);

        videoPlayerView.layer.zPosition = 100;
videoPlayerView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, (30*M_PI)/180, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

**Code to change the anchor Point**

```
if(videoPlayerView.layer.anchorPoint.x != 0.0)
{
    videoPlayerView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);

    videoPlayerView.layer.position = CGPointMake(videoPlayerView.layer.frame.origin.x - videoPlayerView.layer.frame.size.width/2,videoPlayerView.layer.position.y);
}
```

Basically, I have to rotate the Layer like a book flip. I have already done this without using the 30 degree transofrm, but I want it to look more 3D so applied the 30 degree transform along the x axis. So that it looks like the book is placed on a table.

And in order to rotate, setting the anchor point is necessary. If not, please advice otherwise...

Comment: Can you say what are you trying to achieve? How should it look in the end?

Comment: basically, I have to rotate the Layer like a book flip. I have already done this, but I want it to look more 3D so applied the 30 degree transform along the x axis. so that it looks like the book is placed on a table. Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing `anchorPoint`  use

```
CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 50.0000f, 0.0000f, 0.0000f);
```

Translate along X by 50.00 points
Apply 0.40 percent of perspective or you can use the same code you are using right now

rotate the CAlayer using Y .

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
CATransform3D tmp = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0.0146f, 0, 1, 0);
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 50.0000f, 0.0000f, 0.0000f);
tmp = CATransform3DIdentity;
tmp.m34 = 0.0040f;
transform = CATransform3DConcat(transform, tmp);
```

check the [link](https://github.com/erwinmaza/Transformifier) for more reference.

let me know if it works.